# User authentication failing while user login in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a simple login page using python and django. My registration/signup is working fine and I am able to register the user. once the user is registered, while logging in the user using username and password the user is not authenticated. I am not able to find out the exact error, can anyone please guide me through this. 
This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser

# Create your models here.
# create a model for user details with fields username, firstname, lastname,
# emial, password,
class CustomUserInfo(AbstractBaseUser):

    '''
    model for basic user details
    returns username of the user
    '''
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    dob = models.DateField()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['firstname','lastname','username','email','password','dob']

    # return the string form of the object
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

This is my views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, DetailView, ListView
from django.contrib.auth import login,logout,authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from custom_login_app.forms import CustomUserInfoForm
from custom_login_app import models


# Create your views here.

# about template view
class AboutView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'about.html'


# user profile detail page
class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):

    context_object_name = 'user_detail'
    model = models.CustomUserInfo
    template_name = 'userinfo_detail.html'


# home page view
def index(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')

# logout view
@login_required
def customlogout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

# registration view
def registration(request):

    # bool variable to chcek the user is registered
    registered = False

    # check the user has poste the data through the form
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # create a form object
        user_form = CustomUserInfoForm(data=request.POST)

        # check if the form is valid
        if user_form.is_valid():

            # save the entered details to the form object
            user = user_form.save()
            # validate and set the password for hashing
            user.set_password(user.password)
            # save the details
            user.save()
            registered = True

        else:
            print(user_form.errors)

    else:

        # display the registration form
        user_form = CustomUserInfoForm()

    return render(request,'registration.html',{'user_form':user_form,
                                            'registered':registered})

# login view
def customlogin(request):
    # check if the user has posted the details
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Grab the entered username and password
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        # authenticate the entered details using built in django authenticate method
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        # if the user is authenticated, user is available
        if user:

            # check is the user active
            if user.is_active:

                # login the user with the entered details using builtin login module
                login(request,user)

                # Once logged in, redirect to home page
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

                # if user account is not active, resturn a simple HttpResponse
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Your account is not active')

        else:
            # if the user is invalid or has entered invalid details
            print("Someone tried to login with invalid details")
            print("Username:{}, Password:{}".format(username,password))
            return HttpResponse("Invalid Credentials, Please try again!")

    else:
        # if the user has not entered the login details
        return render(request,'login.html',{})
```

My login.html is

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="login">
    <p class="logintext">Please Login</p>
    <form class="form-group loginform" action="{% url 'user_login' %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="usr">
        <label class="usr_label" for="username">Username</label>
        <input class="usr_input" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username"><br/>
      </div>
      <div class="passwd">
        <label class="passwd_label" for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="passwrd_input" type="password"  name="password" placeholder="Enter Password"<br/>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <input class="btn btn-dark login-btn" type="submit" value="Login">
        <a class="btn btn-dark register-btn" href="{% url 'registration' %}">New User?</a>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Any answers will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your login view?

Comment: Its in the views.py file as a function "customlogin"

Answer (score 3):

I think you're setting the password incorrectly when you create the user. Assuming the field name is `password`, it should be:

```
user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `user.is_active` defaults to but, since I don't see it being set in the code you provided, it could be that you never reach the login function because `user.is_active` is `False`

Comment: No i checked by printing the user after authenticating, it should return the username(as the model returns the username) instead i am getting none as the output and if the user.is_active returns false it should print the details in else loop but, i getting output from the second else loop.